# pandas create dataframe without first row of labels

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

This probably gonna be easy for you, but Im new to pandas and just try to learn how to use it.

I have a csv file and try to create dataframe from it. (csv file has no titles on all columns)

```
user_info=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\xxx\user_info.txt','\t')
```

reading is fine, but the result has the first row as data labels and one extra column was added for index. so it became something like following

```
  value1 value2 value3
0 value4 value5 value6
1 ....................
......................
```

so as you may see the index is off postion. 
any idea how to fix this?  either removing index or move index up one row is fine.

I'm looking for following format

```
value1 value2 value3...
value4 value5 value6...
.......................
```

thanks a lot

Comment: What does the data in your csv file actually look like?

Comment: pass `header=None` to `read_csv`.

Comment: `user_info=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\xxx\user_info.txt','\t', header=None)`

Comment: @ayhan: Damn it, 33 secs!

Comment: even with header none, dataframe still has 0,1,2....as first row.....how to get rid of those?

Comment: @ikel: that's not the first row: it's the titles of the columns --- if none given, pandas will number them.

Comment: so the titles can be ignored in this case?

Comment: @ikel: the titles are not part of you data; they are just labels.

Comment: If you want to access the underlying values without the dataframe 'wrapper', you could do `user_info.values`.

Comment: thanks guys can you reform your answer so that i can accept it? thanks @Jan